# What is the definition of convergence in the context of deep neural networks?

Tags: deep-learning, convergence

Suppose I have a feed forward neural network which approximates a value, say $Y_0$. The analytical value of $Y_0$ is given. The plot of the network approximation of $Y_0$ each step is given as follows.

[image]

We can see (visually) that the approximation of $Y_0$ converges to its analytical value. But, how can we mathematically say that the approximation converges?

Note:
There is a definition of the convergence of a sequence.

> A sequence $\lbrace x_n \rbrace_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is said to converge to $x \in \mathbb{R}$ if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a natural number $K(\varepsilon)$ such that for all $n \geq K(\varepsilon$), the terms $x_n$ satisfy $\lvert x_n - x \rvert < \varepsilon$.

In this definition, the sequence is infinite and usually has certain *rules*, for example $\lbrace x_n \rbrace_{n=1}^\infty = \lbrace \frac{1}{n} \rbrace_{n=1}^\infty$. In fact, usually the approximation result of a feed forward neural network (or deep neural network in general) is a finite sequence which has the same number as the epoch/step. Is there a definition of convergence in the context of deep neural networks?

Answer (score 1):

In neural networks, convergence is defined based on the values of the training loss function: if the values of the training loss function follow a descending trend (assuming we are minimizing the loss function, which is the standard), then it converges. If they follow an ascending trend or they are oscillating, then the training is not converging.

We have to take into account some nuances:

- **Stochastic Gradient Descent**: neural networks are usually trained with batch-oriented stochastic gradient descent or some variation of it, so there is usually some noise in the curve. We should ignore the noise when evaluating convergence.
- **Double descent phenomenon**: usually we observe an ascending peak followed by a descending trend (see [this](https://openai.com/research/deep-double-descent)). This is normal and does not preclude convergence. See this exameple:
  [image]
- **Non-stationary training regimes**: while in standard supervised learning we have a stationary training goal, there are other alternatives, like GANs (Generative Adversarial Networks) or reinforcement learning, where we are optimizing against a "moving target". Convergence is more difficult to characterize in those environments.

Note: we should not mistake training convergence for overfitting. Overfitting is a situation where the network memorizes too much of the training data (therefore the training loss goes down), but it performs poorly on unseen data (therefore the validation loss goes up). Neural network training convergence strictly refers to how the training loss behaves.